# No console colors if using npm script inside a Git bash (mintty)

Tags: node.js, windows, git, npm, mintty

### Introduction

Using [**chalk**](https://github.com/sindresorhus/chalk) I have written a small console program for printing colored text, which I execute with [**NodeJS**](http://nodejs.org):

```js
console.log(require('chalk').yellow('yellow text'));
```

The program prints the string *"yellow text"* in yellow. If I execute the script directly with *node*, it outputs:

```bash
$ node test.js
yellow text
```

(the text is actually yellow indeed).

This works independent from the console in which I execute the program.
I tried Windows *cmd.exe* and a [**Git bash**](https://git-for-windows.github.io/) (*mintty*).

### Problem

If I include my program as part of an [npm package.json script](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json), e.g. with

```js
...

"scripts": {
  "example": "node test.js"
}

...
```

and execute it in the *mintty* with

```
$ npm run example

> exampleproject@0.0.1 example D:\exampleproject
> node test.js

yellow text
```

the text is actually **not** yellow but in the console's default color.
But in the Windows *cmd.exe* this works, i.e. the text **is** yellow!

So I assume there must be a problem with the interaction between *mintty* and *npm*. Can I get the text colored even with `npm run example` in *mintty*?

### Used versions

- Windows 7 SP1 64-bit
- Git 2.5.3-32-bit with mintty 2.0.3
- node 4.1.0 32-bit
- npm 2.14.3
- chalk 1.1.1

### Update after more tests

I tried different versions of the involved components, and I guess I nailed it down to *mintty*. The colored *npm* output **worked** with Git, if I configure it with *'Use windows command prompt'* instead of *'Use mintty'* while installation.

After that I tried different versions of mintty to see if it could be a bug:

- With [mintty 1.1.3 inside a MSys 1.0.11](https://sites.google.com/site/axusdev/tutorials/installminttyformsys) the colors did **not** work **at all**, i.e. even the simple `node test.js` had no colored output.
- With the newest mintty 2.1.5 inside a [MSys2 (version 20150916)](http://sourceforge.net/projects/msys2/) the color did **not** work **at all**, too.

**But** the colored output had worked if I used Git bash with mintty 2.0.3 while executing the script directly with `node test.js` (without *npm*).

So now I am totally confused...

Comment: I get the same problem using the latest Git for Windows bundle from git-scm.org (2.6.0). It's MinTTY 2.0.3. I tried `npm install -g chalk-cli` and ran `echo hello world | chalk bold cyan` and the output was not colored :(

Comment: Just add `export FORCE_COLOR=true` to your .bashrc on Windows.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The current work around seems to be (on windows) to set an environment variable:

`FORCE_COLOR=true`

src: [Color support detection problem in git bash on windows](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/1292#issuecomment-258090062)

Comment: Yep, that definitely works just drop it into `.env` and you've got colour

Comment: `.env` I did not know but that would be per project right? In the windows user/system environment variables I meant in my initial answer

Answer (score 13):

It's related to the known problem on Node.js:

[Node.js doesn't run as tty on windows / cygwin nodejs/node#3006](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/3006)

[Git Bash Error - Cannot read property 'substring' #272](https://github.com/SBoudrias/Inquirer.js/issues/272#issuecomment-138375494).

Not sure, if it will ever be fixed.

In short, **MSYS / Cygwin / etc.** (using **Mintty** as terminal emulator) runs bash inside "fake" console, which doesn't get along with node. It will probably be the same for any other terminal emulator.

To check if Node.js is being run in a TTY context try this:

```
cd c:/nodejs
./node -p -e "Boolean(process.stdout.isTTY)"
```

Note, that simply running `node -p -e "Boolean(process.stdout.isTTY)"` won't do the trick in this case.

Comment: Too bad that there is no workaround. But thanks for the enlightenment!

Comment: Is this still true?

Answer (score 9):

Creating the file `~/.bashrc` with the content `export FORCE_COLOR=true` made colors work for me in Git Bash on Windows 10, as pointed out in slightly more general terms by diego nunes and leroyse.

Comment: Works for WSL too

Answer (score 2):

A workaround is to escape the coloured string, replace all the `%1B` by `\u\u%1B` and then, unescape it back.

I'm using chalk here, and it gets automatically disabled when running inside bash...but you can go around it and "force" it to get enabled

```
const chalk = require('chalk')
chalk.enabled = true
chalk.level = 3

function fixColors (str) {
  return unescape(
    escape(
      str
    )
    .replace(/\%1B/i, '\\u%1B')
  )
}

console.log(fixColors(chalk.blueBright('is it blue?!')))
```

I hope this helps someone :)
It's ugly, but easy to implement.

Answer (score 1):

I was successful with adding this to the node js file that was displaying the chalk output:

```
process.env.FORCE_COLOR = true
```