# Preserving colours for text in bash script executing from an npm script

Tags: node.js, bash, npm, npm-scripts

I have a bash script where I echo out some coloured text at the start like so:

echo "\033[1;31mACTION REQUIRED: \033[0m"

And I see that coloured as expected when I run the script from my terminal

[image]

But running as an npm script it ignores the colour expressions, so I just see the literal colour char sequences

[image]

How do I get these to behave when executing in the content of an npm script?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No console colors if using npm script inside a Git bash (mintty)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32742865/no-console-colors-if-using-npm-script-inside-a-git-bash-mintty)

Comment: Use `printf` instead. `echo` does not evaluate escape sequences (like `\e`) on all platforms. On macOS your command will work, for example, but on linux it won't unless you use the `-e` flag.