# How to call NodeJS script inside custom VSCode Extension?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, npm, vscode-extensions

In one of my projects I created a NodeJS script. Now I would like to create a VSCode extension.

How can I link this script to a command inside my custom made extension?

The script should be included in the extension package.

I tried running the script from the terminal, but it wouldn't load the script from within my package.

```
const terminal = vscode.window.createTerminal( 'My Node Script' );
terminal.show();
terminal.sendText( 'npm run myscript', true );
```

How can I achieve this?

**-- Update 02/01/2024**

[image: Colored code]

The colored output seems to work as long as I set **Git bash** as my default terminal in Windows, but I wouldn't like to show the actual `echo` command displayed in the terminal.

Basically the script that I am running is something like:

```
 - Blue color log line: Starting script..
 - Terminal command: abc
 - Blue color log line: Completed step 1
 - Terminal command: xyz
 - Blue color log line: Completed step 2
 - .. etc etc
 - Green color log line: Completed
```

With terminal commands and echo's perferably hidden from output because it looks like this:

[image]

While it is waiting for a command ran by the script, it actually shows like the script completed altogether, but then proceeds to send out more commands (`sendText()`) when the script arrives in the next part.

So the script is not executed in a single terminal execution

What I hope to achieve:

[image]

The closest I got was using `sendTerminal( 'stty -echo' )` from https://askubuntu.com/a/1384471. It would not show the input text anymore, but still show newlines and return to the terminal after each command.

Comment: why do you need to run it using `npm run`? Do you actually need the NPM environment context? Why not just put it in a JS function and register a command that calls that function? https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#commands

Comment: Thank you, it seemed to work! The only thing that I need now is to create a terminal for the command and write all my `console.log()`'s to that terminal

Comment: you know [output channels](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#OutputChannel) are a thing, right?

Comment: @starball Yes I have tried them, but I am trying to figure out how to send colored output like I do when directly calling from NPM. But it seems to me to work in a different for output windows

Comment: yes. read the api docs I linked you. output channels can take a language mode argument, so you can specify syntax highlighting for them just like for editor tabs. indeed, it is different than colouring in terminals, which you'd have to use ANSI escape codes for.

Comment: @starball Thank you! I guess this might be too complicated for the project scope. It's a pity I can't simply transfer the ANSI color encoding when migrating my NPM script to a VSCode extension

Comment: what exactly is this script and what output do you care about the colour of? are you sure there's no commandline argument that forces ANSI escape codes to be printed? it could be that the program is detecting when the output stream is a tty to decide whether to output ANSI escape codes when no colour argument is specified. Ex. see https://stackoverflow.com/q/32742865/11107541

Comment: @starball Sounds interesting! I updated my question.

Comment: you seem to have missed the point of my example link. try setting the `FORCE_COLOR=true` environment variable as shown in the top answer there.

Comment: @starball Which link are you referring to? The link to *commands* or the link to *output channels*? I tried adding `process.env.FORCE_COLOR = 'true';`, then creating an output channel and writing *ANSI* colored output. The color codes are displayed as text without color

Comment: if you want to touch an integrated terminal's shell's environment, see https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#EnvironmentVariableCollection

Comment: @starball Same output of ANSI colors as characters using `context.environmentVariableCollection.replace( 'FORCE_COLOR', 'true' );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Finally I found a solution**

By including the Node script into the extension as a command, then by creating a new terminal, running commands using `child_process` and sending colored output text to the terminal.

To make the terminal logs appear similar to running the Node script, and in color, see below.

[image: Code]

Using `stty -echo` not to display command input characters
https://askubuntu.com/a/1384471

Using `export PS1=''` not to display prompt header
https://askubuntu.com/a/16729/1569633

Using `echo -n` *(and `-e` for colors)* when `echo`ing text to avoid appending new lines